# Apache Nutch 2.3.1 extension point at fetch time

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, nutch

I have configure Hadoop (2.x), Hbase and Nutch 2.3.1 successfully. I have also crawled few sample page also for testing. Now I have to do focussed crawling for specific language using opensource tool cld2. If crawled document does not contain that specific language then that document should not be saved (in Hbase) as well as should not be indexed to Solr. In Nutch [WIKI](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/AboutPlugins), there is not extension point given at fetch time. Is there any other possible way to do the job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no extension point in the fetchers implementation shipped with Nutch. If you think about it you need the document to be fetched and parsed (to extract the language) and then you can write your own `IndexingFilter` in order to check the language of the document and decide if you want to index it or not.

This should not be very difficult to write by yourself. On the other hand for Nutch 1.x we already have this PR https://github.com/apache/nutch/pull/219 which could be easily ported to work on 2.x, and then you'll only need the right JEXL expression.

We already have a `language-identifier` plugin shipped with Nutch 2.x you could probably take a look at how is implemented and add your own integration with cld2 as a different plugin probably. If you want to use cld2 then you'll need to write some parser (along with the indexer) to detect the language from the content.

Comment: Thanks brother. I have implemented language filter at index time. My problem is that I have to remove that document which does not contain Urdu language from Hbase table  (where raw content of document is stored by Nutch at fetch time) not from Solr (where indexed)